# Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_0^x f(x-y) g(y) dy = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I have came up with a proof but now sure if the last part is correct/the best way to do it.

> Let $f(x),g(x)$ be real-valued continuous functions defined on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying the followings:
>
> (a). $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$
>
> (b). $\int_0^\infty \left| g(x) \right| dx < +\infty$
>
> Prove that if $h(x)$ is defined as
>
> \begin{equation}
> h(x) = \int_0^x f(x-y) g(y) dy
> \end{equation}
>
> then $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x) = 0$.

For convenience, let $\int_0^\infty \left| g(x) \right| dx = M$.

Since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$, for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $K_\epsilon > 0 $ such that whenever $x > K_\epsilon$, $\left| f(x) \right| < \epsilon $ holds. If we want $ x - y > K_\epsilon $, then we need $y < x - K_\epsilon$. This gives us

\begin{align}
\left| h(x) \right| &= \left| \int_0^x f(x-y) g(y) dy \right| < \int_0^x \left| f(x-y) \right| \left| g(y) \right| dy\\
& = \int_0^{x - K_\epsilon} \left| f(x-y) \right| \left| g(y) \right| dy + \int_{x - K_\epsilon}^x \left| f(x-y) \right| \left| g(y) \right| dy \\
&< M\epsilon + \int_{x - K_\epsilon}^x \left| f(x-y) \right| \left| g(y) \right| dy
\end{align}

When $y\in [x-K_\epsilon ,x]$, we get can a uniform bound for $f(x-y)$ since $f$ is continuous. Let $f(x-y) \le M'$ for all $y\in [x-K_\epsilon, x]$. Then we now have

\begin{equation}
\left| h(x) \right| \le M \epsilon + M' \int_{x-K_\epsilon}^x \left| g(y) \right| dy
\end{equation}

We claim that as $x\to \infty$, the integral on the right hand side goes to zero. This is because

\begin{align}
\left| \int_{x-K_\epsilon}^x \left| g(y) \right| dy \right| &= \left| \int_0^x \left| g(y) \right| dy - \int_0^{x - K_\epsilon} \left| g(y) \right| dy \right|\\
& = \left| \int_0^x g(y) dy - M + M - \int_0^{x - K_\epsilon} g(y) dy \right|\\
&\le \left| \int_0^x g(y) dy - M\right| + \left| \int_0^{x - K_\epsilon} g(y) dy - M\right| \\
& \le \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon
\end{align}

and since $\int_0^\infty \left| g(x) \right| dx = M$, we can find $P$ such that when $x > P$, both $\int_0^x \left| g(y) \right| dy $ and $\int_0^{x - K_\epsilon} \left| g(y) \right| dy $ are small.

As a result, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left| h(x) \right| = 0$.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: That's good. I would shorten the last section. You're trying to show that $ \int_{x-K_\epsilon}^x \left| g(y) \right| dy\to 0$. But $ \int_{x-K_\epsilon}^x \left| g(y) \right| dy\leq  \int_{x-K_\epsilon}^\infty \left| g(y) \right| dy = M- \int_0^{x-K_\epsilon} \left| g(y) \right| dy\to0$. Done.

Comment: Can we give a precious definition for $P$ which is based on the functions f and g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using Lebesgue's dominated convergence.

$$|h(x)|\le \int_0^x |f(x-y)g(y)|~dy=\int_0^{\infty}1_{(0,x)}|f(x-y)g(y)|~dy$$

Then note that since $f\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$ and $f$ is continuous, we have that $f$ is bounded by some $M$. So $1_{(0,x)}|f(x-y)g(y)|\le M|g(y)|$ and by assumption $g$ is absolutely integrable. So we may apply dominated convergence. Note for any $y$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} 1_{(0,x)}|f(x-y)g(y)|=0$. The result follows.

Comment: I read about Dominated Convergence Theorem, but it only talks about sequence of measurable functions? I don't see any sequence here...

Comment: @Misakov Let $f_n(y)=f(n-y)$. Note $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n-y)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x-y)=0$.

Comment: So we first get rid of $x$ in the upper bound by using indicator function, then we "change" $x$ to $n$ (since they are equivalent, though i need some time to think through), and finally we use dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @Misakov yeah that's right. It shouldn't be too hard to see why if we have convergence on $\Bbb{R}$ we have convergence on $\Bbb{N}$, as $\Bbb{N}\subset \Bbb{R}$